# can't call a function from within another function

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

Hi I am trying to use tkinter to create a page with a button that when pressed will change the state of an entry box on that page from read-only to normal.

here is my code where the function called by the button is within the class my script still runs but the button does nothing:

```
class playlist(tkinter.Frame): #creates playlist page              
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


    A4 = tkinter.Canvas(self, bg="black", bd=20, height=1080, width=1920, relief="sunken") #creates black background
    AC = tkinter.Label(self, bg="white", bd=5, height=45, width=225,) #creates white canvas
    B1 = tkinter.Button(self, anchor="center", height=1, width=6, bg="#16EBF2", activebackground="#23F216",  relief="sunken", 
                        font=("Elephant", 24), text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(homepage))
    B2 = tkinter.Button(self, anchor="center", height=1, width=4, bg="#16EBF2", activebackground="#23F216", relief="sunken",
                        font=("Elephant", 24), text="Edit", command=lambda: edit)
    E1 = tkinter.Entry(self, state="readonly", text="Name:", bd=5, bg="red", font=("Elephant", 24), exportselection=0)

    E1.pack()
    A4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    AC.pack()
    B1.pack()
    B2.pack()

    A4.create_window(960, 550, anchor="center", window=AC) #puts new canvas on background
    A4.create_window(200, 80, anchor="center", window=B1) #adds buttons to canvas
    A4.create_window(960, 80, anchor="center", window=E1)
    A4.create_window(650, 80, anchor="center", window=B2)

def edit():    
    E1.configure(state = "normal")
    B2.configure(text="Done")
    E1.pack()
    B2.pack()
    App.update_idletasks()
```

this way the function cant define E1 or B2
so I tried a version where the function is within the first function:

```
class playlist(tkinter.Frame): #creates playlist page              
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


    A4 = tkinter.Canvas(self, bg="black", bd=20, height=1080, width=1920, relief="sunken") #creates black background
    AC = tkinter.Label(self, bg="white", bd=5, height=45, width=225,) #creates white canvas
    B1 = tkinter.Button(self, anchor="center", height=1, width=6, bg="#16EBF2", activebackground="#23F216",  relief="sunken", 
                        font=("Elephant", 24), text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(homepage))
    B2 = tkinter.Button(self, anchor="center", height=1, width=4, bg="#16EBF2", activebackground="#23F216", relief="sunken",
                        font=("Elephant", 24), text="Edit", command=lambda: edit)
    E1 = tkinter.Entry(self, state="readonly", text="Name:", bd=5, bg="red", font=("Elephant", 24), exportselection=0)

    E1.pack()
    A4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    AC.pack()
    B1.pack()
    B2.pack()

    A4.create_window(960, 550, anchor="center", window=AC) #puts new canvas on background
    A4.create_window(200, 80, anchor="center", window=B1) #adds buttons to canvas
    A4.create_window(960, 80, anchor="center", window=E1)
    A4.create_window(650, 80, anchor="center", window=B2)

    def edit():    
        E1.configure(state = "normal")
        B2.configure(text="Done")
        E1.pack()
        B2.pack()
        App.update_idletasks()
```

this way the script still runs and the button still does nothing.
No errors just not working.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main recommendation would be to have a look at python classes without tkinter first, and get comfortable with constructing a class before coming back to it.

Basically, you need to assign your tkinter widgets to attributes of your class, so that they can be referenced from anywhere else in your class. ie. when you're creating your buttons that have to be referenced later in your `edit` method, assign them to attributes:

```
self.B1 = tkinter.Button(self, ...)
self.B2 = tkinter.Button(self, ...)
```

Then for your `edit` method to be able to access them later, the class instance, `self`, is passed to it, so you have to give your edit method a `self` parameter, ie.

```
def edit(self):
    # then you can reference your attributes which store the widgets
    self.B1.config(...)
```

Finally, the command for your button `self.B2` simply needs to be a reference to the `edit` method, you don't need a lambda statement, ie.

```
Button(...command=self.edit)
```

Comment: Hi, ive changed the command to command=self.edit but my edit function still cant read E1 or B1 from the previous function. with change when i click the button i get this error

Comment: "Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"H:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
     return self.function(*args)
TypeError: edit() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: Sorry, can't believe I didn't spot that, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i needed. :)